# PHP error_log not logging when script is ran from shell

Tags: php, apache, logging

Here's a basic test script to show the issue I am having:

**test1.php**

```
<?php
     error_log('hello');
?>
```

This works fine. Opening http://exmaple.com/test will log 'hello' into /var/log/apache2/error.log.

Now I have this, to run test.php in the background:

**test2.php**

```
<?php
    shell_exec("/usr/bin/php /var/www/test.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
?>
```

I'm aware that the `stderr` is redirected to `/dev/null` in this example, but I have also tried it without `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` and still no logging occurs.

I did also try setting the error_log path in test.php using `ini_set('error_log','/var/log/apache2/error.log');`

Is there a way to get it to log correctly?

Comment: Hey, I just noticed StackOverflow changed their logo ... Is it Gay Pride week?

Comment: There was me trying to make a joke at the new logo ... And it actually is gay pride week ...

Comment: php when executed from CLI does not log to apaches log file. That would not make sense and most likely it does not have permission to do so. Typically there are separate php.ini files for cli and http server mode. And typically php on cli logs to stderr. Which you do not pick up in the code above.

Comment: @arkascha It doesn't log to apache log files by default. I tried the code from the answer, and it worked.

Comment: I am pretty sure that your attempt with `ini_set('error_log','/var/log/apache2/error.log');` _does_ refer to an apache log file. Which typically will not work as mentioned because of file permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
<?php
ini_set('error_log', '/home/user/error.log');
error_log('hello');
```

Output:

```
[27-Jun-2015 11:20:55 UTC] hello
```

Make sure, that you have permission to write into the log file when you run the script from console.